# How can I draw this diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw this diagram in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: Yes. (As an answer this would be about as helpful as the question)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TikZ - flowchart nodes alignment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139136/tikz-flowchart-nodes-alignment). And many other TikZ questions about flowcharts and similar

Comment: In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: Why would you want to, though?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By way of stacks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
{\footnotesize\stackanchor{Self-adjusted}{Market}}
$\leftarrow$
\Centerstack{1840s -- 1870s\\$\downarrow$\\Adam Smith \& David Ricardo\\
  $\downarrow$\\ \small Restriction on Economic Competition}
$\rightarrow$
{\footnotesize\stackanchor{Comparitive}{Advantage}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Stackengine to the rescue!  ;-)

Comment: @JPi Takes a whacking and keeps on stacking!

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
   \documentclass{article}



\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={align=center}]
\node (a) at (0,0) {Adam Smith \& David Ricardo};
\node[below=of a] (b) {Restriction on Economic Competition};
\node[above=of a] (c) {1840s--1870s};
\node[left=of a] (d) {Self--adjusted\\Market};
\node[right=of a] (e) {Comparative\\Advantage};
\draw[->] (c.south)--(a.north);
\draw[->] (a.west)--(d.east);
\draw[->] (a.east)--(e.west);
\draw[->] (a.south)--(b.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```